# Oracle UTL_HTTP conection to RESTful webservice

Tags: oracle, web-services, post

I tried a few days to access a REST webservice and the response is an HTML:

> 10.4.16 415 Unsupported Media Type
>   The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

It works from browser (mozila). the request:

```
https://xmlhub-test.xxx.xx/xmlhubws/jersey/SubmitMessage

POST /xmlhubws/jersey/SubmitMessage HTTP/1.1

Host: xmlhub-test.xxx.xx

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://portal-test.xxx.xx/portal/page/portal/xxx/extranet/opma_main/xxxx/wsclient-xmlhub.html
Cookie: JSESSIONID=JjhpJTqKsRYFGCjL3QLV2GcYMJHLvLDVlBL5hyh5FN8K2qyb10PR!-621147356!625535808; ObSSOCookie=s47sUDozSHzJ%2FarHPqrcaD5LkcFJXEmkuTQKr51UYXa3lZPjeNHKjzaUmxYbPxLkZYaaztIqCJwodlHpo6D4jR%2FVkKhmd%2Bcc9dJg4jw9cA3Kn%2FZxiwe3RA1Fyf2A%2BFLgy6eQStLzV6C9QbOi2lersS9gZBbYEy28etCXhPgMuOavl3Xtnf%2BeMVCj4Hg2QQxZSt%2FHjkSWRh%2FyVhDevt2yUo4zpoLTZ7ZKX28um6FO8CCXUTCvSlljWSzhzmSL9SwO;     RSERVER_XMLHUB_TEST_TCP_7012=R1894177232
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------204562724022109
Content-Length: 2607
-----------------------------204562724022109
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="abc-01.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

ETC

and my code is:

```
--UTL_HTTP.CLOSE_PERSISTENT_CONNS (g_wsdl_url);

   utl_http.set_response_error_check( false );
   utl_http.set_detailed_excp_support( true );
   utl_http.set_cookie_support( true );
   utl_http.set_transfer_timeout( 60 );
   utl_http.set_follow_redirect( 3 );
   utl_http.set_persistent_conn_support( true );    

   UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET(xxxx, xxxxx);

   v_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('https://xmlhub-test.xxx.xx/xmlhubws/jersey/SubmitMessage','POST','HTTP/1.1');
   utl_http.set_body_charset(v_http_request, 'UTF-8');

   utl_http.set_authentication (v_http_request, xxxx, xxxxxx,'Basic',false);

   UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'Host','xmlhub-test.xxx.xx');         
   UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'Accept-Language','en-us,en;q=0.5');
   --UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate');       
   UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'Connection','keep-alive');
   --UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'Referer','https://portal-test.bnr.ro/portal/page/portal/BNR/extranet/opma_main/opma/wsclient-xmlhub.html');
   --text/html; charset=UTF-8 --'multipart/form-data'
   utl_http.set_header(v_http_request,'Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
   utl_http.set_header (v_http_request, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');          
   utl_http.set_header(v_http_request,'Content-Length', l_clob_len);         
   utl_http.set_header(v_http_request,'id', '"downloadMessage"');


    utl_http.write_text(v_http_request,p_xml.getStringVal());
```

what can i do? what cand i try. I tried dozens of variations (> 180 xml files request).
Please help me. 
Tjank you!

Comment: change `utl_http.set_header(v_http_request,'Content-Type','multipart/form-data')` to `utl_http.set_header(v_http_request,'Content-Type','application/xml')`  and try again

Comment: I tried this but it does not work

Comment: I have the same code for GET:
       v_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('https://xmlhub-test.xxx.xx/xmlhubws/jersey/checkMessageState','GET','HTTP/1.1');
                
       utl_http.set_authentication (v_http_request, xxx, xxxx,'Basic',false);
 
 
       UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'Host','xmlhub-test.xxx.xx');

Comment: I can not get there. I tried another function:
v_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('https://xmlhub-test.xxx.xx/xmlhubws/jersey/CheckMessageState?id=1077','GET','HTTP/1.1');
utl_http.set_authentication (v_http_request, xxxxx, xxxxx,'Basic',false);
UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request,'HOST','xmlhub-test.xxx.xx'); 
 
>> The requested URL /xmlhubws/jersey/CheckMessageState was not found.
Form browser:
https://xmlhub-test.xxx.xx/xmlhubws/jersey/CheckMessageState?id=1077
GET /xmlhubws/jersey/CheckMessageState?id=1077 HTTP/1.1
Host: xmlhub-test.xxx.xx

I ran out of ideas and out of energy.

Comment: GET works without set heder 'Host'.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, works:

```
BOUNDARY CONSTANT VARCHAR2(240) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';


UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET(wallet_path, wallet_pwd);

v_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('https://xmlhub-test.xxx.xx/SubmitMessage','POST','HTTP/1.1');
utl_http.set_body_charset(v_http_request, 'UTF-8');

utl_http.set_authentication (v_http_request, user, password,'Basic',false);                                

UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0');
UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request, 'Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request, 'Accept-Language', 'en-us,en;q=0.5');
UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request, 'Connection', 'keep-alive');
UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request, 'Referer', 'https://portal-test.xxx.xx');
UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
UTL_HTTP.set_header(v_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary="'|| BOUNDARY || '"');

utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, '--' || BOUNDARY|| utl_tcp.CRLF);    
utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="opma.xml"' || utl_tcp.crlf);
utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, 'Content-Type: text/xml' || utl_tcp.crlf);
utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, v_send);


utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, utl_tcp.crlf );
utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, '--' || BOUNDARY||'--');
utl_http.write_text(v_http_request, utl_tcp.crlf );

v_http_response := utl_http.get_response(v_http_request);
```